# nginx+gunicorn+django error Not Found: /static/.. file

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, django-staticfiles

I built a python web framework by using django, and I want to deploy it with nginx and gunicorn. However, I keep getting prompted for error about "Not Found: /static/answer/result.png". If I didn't use nginx adnd gunicorn I wouldn't get this error. I don't know what went wrong, please help me, thank you.

(1) settings.py file:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SECRET_KEY = '...%a..............'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", "192.168.43.90", "192.168.2.229"]


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    "gunicorn",
    'UserProfile',
    'ImageRecognition',
    "KuaiChao",
    "HuaXiao"
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'LPAI.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'LPAI.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = "static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),
)
```

(2) /etc/nginx/sites-avaiable/default file

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name 192.168.2.229;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            proxy_pass 192.168.2.229:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /static {
            autoindex on;
            alias  /home/guomin/resource/gitee/lapi_lz/static; # django app static file
    #        root /root/exampledir/static/;
     }
}
```

(3) The command I used to start django: `gunicorn LPAI.wsgi:application -w 4 -b 192.168.2.229:5000`

(4) I get error: `Not Found: /static/answer/EJE005/EJE005_1-1367351883672326145-1367316751137640449-result.png`
Note that this image **exists** and its path is `/home/guomin/resource/gitee/lapi_lz/static/answer/EJE005/EJE005_1-1367351883672326145-1367316751137640449-result.png`

The above is all the relevant information, please help me.

Comment: `DEBUG = True` why True? Should be False with nginx+gunicorn.

Comment: @IvanStarostin And the secret key shouldn't be `'secret'` either for that matter ;-)

Comment: Does the web server have sufficient permissions to read the `/home/guomin/resource/gitee/lapi_lz/static` directory?

Comment: Have you run ```python manage.py collectstatic``` command ?

Comment: Dear, I set DEBUG=True to find out what's wrong. I also set bebug=False，but still to no image are displayed. @lvan Starostin.

Comment: Dear, I have run this piece of code : python3 manage.py collectstatic. But still it still didn't solve my problem. @josephthomaa

Comment: Dear, web server should have sufficient permissions because the image can be displayed normally when the nginx+gunicron is not used for deployment. Besides, "SECRET_KEY = 'secret'" is copied and automatically converted to this, I have modified it. @AKX

Comment: Can be displayed normally how? Gunicorn and Nginx are likely to run as different users, as is the runserver development server.

Comment: Dear, related html file code is " <img id="image_result" src="{% static image_name %}" width="100%" style="border:2px solid #428bca" onclick="onClick(this)"> ". I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you said in the last sentence. @AKX

Comment: When you are using `manage.py runserver` to run your code, it is being run as the user you invoke that command as. When you are using `gunicorn` to run your Django WSGI app (as e.g. that user), it does not serve the static files; the web server does. The web server may run as a different user, who might not have permission to read the directory the static files reside in. Use `ls -l` to ensure the permissions for the directory are correct.

Comment: Dear, I found that port 80 is occupied. And I add the following statement "url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)/$', serve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})". The problem is solved. I didn't figure out the problem. Thank you for your help.

Comment: for me this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295644/static-files-are-not-found-gunicorn helped.