# Static files are not found (gunicorn)

Tags: python, django, nginx, webserver, gunicorn

I know this question was already asked frequently. But the supposed solutions seem not to help me.

Here is my Nginx definition for the static files

```
    location /static/ {
        alias /data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/static;
    }
```

Here my Django settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

I did run already

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

However, I get

> Not Found: /static/js/xxxx.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your nginx declaration causes the issue.

**Could you please try this:**

```sh
location /static/ {
    # static files
    autoindex on;
    autoindex_exact_size off;
    # /data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp <-- may be in your case
    root /exact/path/to/project/folder;
}
```

**Instead of this:**

```sh
location /static/ {
    alias /data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/static;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error related to incorrect usage of `alias` nginx directive is discussed over and over again on SO. Lets assume you have a request `http://example.com/static/js/script.js`. Normalized URI of this request which is processed by nginx `location /static/ { ... }` directive is `/static/js/script.js`
When you have an `alias /data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/static;` directive inside that location, nginx removes `/static/` prefix used in `location` directive from the URI and appends the rest to the path given in `asias` directive. This result is concatenation of `/data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/static` and `js/script.js` strings which gives you wrong `/data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/staticjs/script.js` file path/name. So general rule of writing the path when you use an `alias` directive is to use the trailing slash in the path when you had that slash in your `location` directive and don't use it otherwise. This means that when you use an `alias` directive you should use either

```
location /static {
    alias /data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/static;
}
```

or

```
location /static/ {
    alias /data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/static/;
}
```

location blocks for your static files (I think the second one is preferred).

On the other side a `root` directive appends its path to the full request URI. As nginx documentation [states](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias),

> When location matches the last part of the directive’s value:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     alias /data/w3/images/;
> }
> ```
>
> it is better to use the [`root`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) directive instead:
>
> ```
> location /images/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```

So @Sabil [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69295825/7121513) is right (although it is missing the explanation) and you'd better use

```
location /static/ {
    root /data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp;
}
```

This way for the `http://example.com/static/js/script.js` request the path `/data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp` will be concatenated with the normalized URI `/static/js/script.js` given you correct `/data/atsi_webapp/ATSi_WebApp/static/js/script.js` file name/path. Since every normalized URI starts with the slash, you are not required to add that slash to the end of `root` directive argument although adding it won't cause so many harm as missing required slash at the end of `alias` directive argument.