# the server does not distribute django + gunicorn + nginx static

Tags: django, nginx, deployment, static, gunicorn

On my ubuntu 20.04 I am trying to deploy a Django 3.2.8 project using nginx and gunicorn. The problem is that the server cannot find the static. Because of this, the pages are displayed without css and images.

I tried many solutions from the internet but nothing helped me. Thank you in advance for your time!

at first im start this script (start_gunicorn.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash
source /root/myapps/zhanna_first_web/env/bin/activate
exec gunicorn -c /root/myapps/zhanna_first_web/zhanna/gunicorn_config.py lawyer>
```

gunicorn_config.py:

```
command = '/root/myapps/zhanna_first_web/env/bin/gunicorn'
pythonpath = '/root/myapps/zhanna_first_web/zhanna'
bind = '185.46.8.164:8001'
workers = 3
user = 'root'
limit_request_fields = 32000
limit_request_field_size = 0
raw_env = 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=lawyer.settings'
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name 185.46.8.164;

   location /static {
      autoindex on;
      root /myapps/zhanna_first_app/zhanna/static;
   }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://185.46.8.164:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

Ubuntu responds to the launch of the start_gunicorn script with this output.

```
[2022-01-09 09:53:31 +0300] [76583] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-01-09 09:53:31 +0300] [76583] [INFO] Listening at: http://185.46.8.164:8001 (76583)
[2022-01-09 09:53:31 +0300] [76583] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-01-09 09:53:31 +0300] [76585] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 76585
[2022-01-09 09:53:31 +0300] [76586] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 76586
[2022-01-09 09:53:31 +0300] [76587] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 76587
```

After that, the site is launched and is available at 185.46.8.164:8001. I can open different pages of the site, but static is not available.

From the error log, I realized that the server is accessing the correct folder for static. That is, he is looking for it in the folder where it is. But for some reason he does not see it there and gives ERROR 404 NOT FOUND

P.S
I've really tried a lot of things. For example, I changed the ip in the configs from 127.0.01 to the real ip of my server and back. I changed the configs "location /static" to "location /static/" and back. Then I changed the paths from /path/to to path/to/static and back. Changed alias to root and back. And much more that is offered on forums on the Internet

I hope that you can help me, because I have completely run out of ideas

Comment: Use `root /myapps/zhanna_first_app/zhanna;` instead. check the difference between `root` and `alias` nginx directives to understand the mistake you did.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static files are not found (gunicorn)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69295644/static-files-are-not-found-gunicorn)

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but it still didn't help me. Now, for some reason, there are no records of attempts in the logs, but yesterday I managed to understand that the path is being created correctly. That is, the server creates the correct path to the folder with static. There is static in this folder. But he doesn't see her in it

Answer (score 1):

use location **/static/**   instead of /static

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name 185.46.8.164;

        
            location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
            location /static/ {
                root /myapps/zhanna_first_app/zhanna/static;
            }
            location /media/  {
                root /path-to-media-folder;
            }
    
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://185.46.8.164:8001;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
    }
```

Make sure to run collectstatic and restat nginx

Comment: Unfortunately, this option didn't help me.

Comment: post the your settings.py file   ( portion having static file details)

Comment: do you set static root properly?

Comment: from os.path import join
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

....
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

Comment: after running collect static, does all your static files coped to static  folder

Comment: 0 static files copied to '/root/myapps/zhanna_first_web/zhanna/static', 190 unmodified.

Comment: means static files are already collected successfully

Comment: location /static/ {
                root /myapps/zhanna_first_app/zhanna/static;
            }

Comment: I did a typo in the static file configuration  , put two root  , make sure only once is uses

Comment: I made sure that the configuration uses one root. And I inserted "location /static/ { root /my apps/zhanna_first_app/zhanna/static; }" into the configuration, but it didn't help. Besides, I've tried it before

Comment: Is there a chance that the server does not have enough rights or something like that? Perhaps something prevents the server from seeing the files in the static folder

Comment: might be a reason

Comment: please check it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588498/gunicorn-nginx-django-inside-of-a-docker-container-gunicorn-successfully-run/70590349#70590349

Comment: gunicorn.service file (unit file) help to run gunicorn as a service, and can be managed using systemctl

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the error was that nginx was giving a 502 error. I reconfigured my files and the 502 error went away. But now I have met the 500 error.

line from /var/log/nginx/error.log :

```
worker_connections are not enough while connecting to upstream...
```

my configs:
my_app.conf (nginx config):

```
server {
    listen 82;
    server_tokens off;
    server_name 185.46.8.164;

    #root /var/www/
    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/app/myapp/socket;
        #
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        #
        proxy_pass http://185.46.8.164:82;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /eva/static;
    }

}
```

myapp.ini (uwsgi.ini file):

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /root/eva/lawyer
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE= lawyer.settings.production
wsgi-file = lawyer/wsgi.py
#module = lawyer.uwsgi:application
workers = 1
max-requests = 5000
#plugins-dir=/usr/lib/uwsgi/plugins/
#plugins = python3
#virtualenv = /root/eva/venv
home = /root/eva/venv
processes = 5
threads = 2
master = true
die-on-term = true
socket = /run/sedova.sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true
uid = www-data
gui = www-data
```

I found two ways on the Internet. 1) Change my_app.conf. But the changes didn't help me. 2) In /etc/nginx/nginx.conf, change the value of worker_connections and add the worker_rlimit_nofile parameter. But too large values cause me the socket() failed... error (shown below). And too small - do not solve the problem.
socket() failed (24: To many open files)...