# Django cant load static files - 404 error

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

I've looked on stackoverflow for info and tried to fix it but it didn't work! I've been trying to search for the past 2 weeks but I'm still getting 404 static files. Under local, everything still loads normally

The server I use is: Django + Gunicorn + Nginx

Here is the file I loaded and configured! Please take a look and see where I went wrong!

Thanks everyone!

```
/staticfiles
/apps
    /templates
        /includes
           scripts.html
    /static
        /assets
           /vendor
               /jquery
                   /dist  
                        jquery.min.js
    /home
/core
```

templates:

```
  {% load static %}
  <script src="{%static 'assets/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
```

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'resultSaved',
    'channels',
    'apps.home',
    'apps.templates'  
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = 'core.asgi.application'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(CORE_DIR, 'apps/static'),
)
```

Ngnix config

```
server {
    server_name *******;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        alias /home/django/magi/src/staticfiles;
    }
    
     location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
    

   location /ws/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass *******:8001;
    }




}server {
    if ($host = *******;) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = *******;) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name *******;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

If you need to check any files, please comment below so I can add them!

Comment: Add the trailing slash to your `alias /home/django/magi/src/staticfiles` directive. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69296739/7121513) answer for the explanation.

Comment: OMG it's working!!!!!!!!

Thanks you very much!

Comment: I don't want to post duplicates, but you can upwote the answer I'm referring to if you want :)

Comment: @N.Tuyen Don't know if this will help, but I believe your django apps should be on top of INSTALLED_APPS